# "-std=c++17 do not recognize by the command line" when build in sublime text in windows

Tags: c++

I have the following code in my program. By default, `nullptr` is not recognized by the compiler or it is not defined in the default c++ build system version in sublime. So I created a new build system that is c++17 then this problem arise.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(int _int)
    {
        data = _int;
        next = nullptr;
    }

};

int main()
{

}
```

When I build the program, the error below shows up.

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++17"
```

I already made a new build system...

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o",               
    "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , 
    "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
    "shell":true,
    "working_dir":"$file_path",
    "selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

What causes this error and how should I fixed it?

Comment: and so, what version of `g++` are you using?

Comment: when I run `g++ version` in my cmd. It says...`

g++: unrecognized option '-version'
g++: no input files`

Comment: @EricEchemane `g++ --version`

Comment: I got...g++ (TDM-2 mingw32) 4.4.1

Comment: should I upgrade this?

Comment: well that's not going to support C++17 because it's about a decade old.

Comment: That's a really ancient version. Get a newer version of GCC/Clang or MSVC.

Comment: `tdm-gcc` looks like mostly abandonware at this point; try MSYS2/MinGW64 instead: https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Do note that this has nothing to do with sublime-text as it's not a compiler

Comment: GCC 4.4.1 was released in 2009. You cannot expect this version to support the C++ Standard from 2017.

Comment: where should I get the latest gcc compiler?

Comment: I've installed MSY2, should it fix the problem?